# How to make ProgressDialog non-stop loading circle when I am loading a list of photos?

Tags: android, multithreading, download, progressdialog

I am downloading an array of photos from the net and showing a ProgressDialog with a loading circle. But the loading circle will be lag / hang while the process is not finish. How to make the loading running smoothly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Show a indeterminate ProgressDialog object. Then start a thread and download the images using the thread. Dismiss the ProgressDialog after the download is complete. This method works for me.